# How make one linux directory path "point" to a different path

Tags: linux, bash, vim, path

I just changed distros and I have umpteen bash and vim scripts throughout various file systems which reference the path '/mnt/0' that now need to reference the path '/media/q/fs-uuid' instead.

Is there any command in bash I could set that would act like a pointer, so that any reference to /mnt/0 would actually go to /media/q/fs-uuid?

Neither alias or ln seem to do what I need, and I'd rather not use grep and sed if there is a way to set this just once only.

Comment: Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/557867/693277).

Comment: You might want to consider going through all those scripts ((semi-)automated with Vim, of course!) and introduce something like a `${MOUNTPOINT:-/mnt/0}` variable, so you won't have to create that pointer, not now, and not when this'll change again in the future.